# Nested functions in for loop not working

Tags: bash, shell

Nested functions in for loop seems to be not working as expected. The loop breaks after iterating once

```
# copy files
copyFiles () {
   for (( i=0; i<${#filetype[@]}; ++i )); do
     //some code goes here
   done
}

# copy common components
copyComponents () {
  copyFiles $1
}

for (( i=0; i<3; ++i )); do
  echo $i //iterates only once.. expectation is thrice
  case $1 in
    components)
       copyComponents $module;;
    *)
       echo "unknown type"
   esac
done
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but for loop exits after iterating once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all variables in shell are global unless declared otherwise. Here's a simpler example that demonstrates this:

```
func () {
    for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do
        echo "func: $i"
    done
}

for ((i=0; i<5; ++i)); do
    echo "Loop: $i"
    func
done

echo "$i"
```

If you run the, you'll see that after `func` is executed the first time, the value of the global variable `i` is 11, which causes the outer loop to exit. To fix this in `bash`, you can ensure that the loop counter in your function stays local.

```
copyFiles () {
    local i
    for (( i=0; i<${#filetype[@]}; ++i )); do
        # some code goes here
    done
}
```